# Updating files takes very long? Is there any way to short it?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, raspberrypi

Im trying to copy one folder to another. There are the same and I need to merge them. I tried this command:

```
rsync -azr "$TEMP" "$TARGET"
```

Im using raspbian and raspberry pi zero but it takes very long that folder will be updated. Is there any solution that cheks if in temp folder are newest file and it updates faster?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using rsync over the network. You should not use the `-z` option for compression. The compression is useful when you use rsync over the network and have a limited bandwidth. If you are using it locally, it will just require more CPU usage. So removing this option should improve the performance.